# Converting List of rating to List of average rating with java streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have a problem with streams in Java, which is bothering me for whole day. So I will be more then glad if someone can help me.

I have two classes Rate and AvgRate:

```
class Rate {
    private int itemId;
    private int userId;
    private int rate;

    [...]
}

class AvgRate {
    private int itemId;
    private int avgRate;

    [...]
}
```

So let say that I have list of Rates:

```
//Rate(itemId, userId, rate)
List<Rate> rates = Arrays.asList(
    new Rate(1, 1, 3),
    new Rate(1, 2, 1),
    new Rate(1, 3, 4),
    new Rate(1, 4, 2),
    new Rate(2, 1, 5),
    new Rate(2, 2, 1),
    new Rate(3, 3, 2),
);
```

Now I want to calculate average rating for each item and put it into List e.g.

```
//(itemId, avgRating)
List<AvgRate> avgRates = {
    (1, 2,5),
    (2, 3),
    (3, 2)
}
```

So the question ins how can i do this operation using Java stream.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Use `Collectors.groupingBy(Rate::getItemId)` combined with a `Collectors.mapping(Rate::getRate)` and a `Collectors.averagingInt` for the downstream.

Comment: where are your attempts?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> avgInteger = rates.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Rate::getItemId, Collectors.averagingInt(Rate::getRate));

List<AvgRate> avgRates = avgInteger.entrySet().stream()
  .map(entry -> new AvgRate(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The first block transforms your List into a `Map` of `itemId`s and the average of the `rate`s. The second block transforms that `Map` back into a `List`.